# Can't find nextElement / nextElementSibling in DOM. Is it because it's a img?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble finding the next element in the DOM with some JavaScript code.
I want to change the img src but when I try to access the img element I get 'null' even though it is there.

Thanks
P

I've tried nextElement and nextElementSibling to no avail

```js
var node1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0');
console.log('1 ... ' + node1.id);
var node1img = document.getElementById(node1.id).href;
console.log('3 ... ' + node1img);
console.log('3 ... ' + document.getElementById(node1.id).nextElementSibling);
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinks_Data,0,ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0,&#39; &#39;,ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0Nodes)">
        <img src="http://intranetnlb/PublishingImages/plus.gif" alt="Expand &lt;div class=&#39;treeviewHeadingPre&#39;>&lt;/div>&lt;div class=&#39;treeviewHeading&#39;>An Post Subsidiaries&lt;/div>" style="border-width:0;" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd hope to find the img tag

Comment: That's invalid markup

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen Changing the structure of the markup, in case of `nextSibling, nextElementSibling`, can be quite "harmful". A text node might change everything...

Comment: [mcve] please. IDs can be minimized, alt attribute is breaking the HTML, style can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<img>` is a child of your `a` Element. It's not next to it:

```
node1.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
```

Note that `document.getElementById(node1.id)` is redundant as `node1` already contains the element.

---

Demo by getting the `src` attribute as example:

```js
var node1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0');
console.log('1 ... ' + node1.id);
var node1img = node1.href;
console.log('3 ... ' + node1img);
console.log('3 ... ' + node1.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src);
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinks_Data,0,ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0,&#39; &#39;,ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0Nodes)">
        <img src="http://intranetnlb/PublishingImages/plus.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0;" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Node:** The `alt` tag of your `<img>` seems to be breaking your markup as it's content isn't escaped properly. Therefore I removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`img` is not a sibling which can be accessed with `nextElement` or `nextElementSibling` but instead it is a children element of `a` which can be accessed with `.children`

So the final code would be

```js
var node1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0');
console.log('1 ... ' + node1.id);
var node1img = node1.children[0]; // first child which is the img element
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinks_Data,0,ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0,&#39; &#39;,ctl00_ctl39_g_1398ff2c_c26e_44d8_b382_346b589f7224_tvLinksn0Nodes)">
        <img src="http://intranetnlb/PublishingImages/plus.gif" alt="Expand &lt;div class=&#39;treeviewHeadingPre&#39;>&lt;/div>&lt;div class=&#39;treeviewHeading&#39;>An Post Subsidiaries&lt;/div>" style="border-width:0;" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

to change the src of the image you can use `node1img.src = 'newUrl'`!

Comment: I'd use `.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]` instead of `.children[0]` since we want to make sure it's actually an image.